# Getting Ajax variable after success parameter

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here's my Ajax code:

```
       $("#generateImage").click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
       var currentUrl =window.location.href;
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: url,
            data: "{'urlVar':'"+ currentUrl +"','mywidth':'250','myheight':'480'}",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null && response.success) {
                    alert("Success");
                  window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController", new { urlVar = currentUrl })';
                } else {

                    alert("Failed");

                }
            },

        });
```

In this part of code:

```
new { urlVar = currentUrl })';
```

currentUrl says:

> Does not exist in the current context;

My Question is:
How to make `currentUrl` to be valid on that particular location?

Otherwise there's no error on `data:` part? `data: "{'urlVar':'"+ currentUrl`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `currentUrl` defined as client-side variable in this line:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

Note that `@Url.Action()` helper is executed server-side, you cannot use `currentUrl` client-side variable inside it as action parameter (it doesn't exist as server-side variable). You need to use query string like this to redirect into `GetData` action method:

```
if (response != null && response.success) {
    alert("Success");

    // use query string here
    window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController")?urlVar=' + currentUrl;
}
```

If you want to get URL from server-side, modify your `Url.Action` helper to include either `Request.Url`, `Request.RawUrl` or `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`:

```
// alternative 1
window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController", new { urlVar = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri })';

// alternative 2
window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController", new { urlVar = Request.Url.ToString() })';
```

**Update:**

For multiple parameters, you can utilize either query string parameters:

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController")?urlVar=' + currentUrl + '&width=' + varwidthvalue + '&height=' + varheightvalue;
```

Or if both `varwidthvalue` and `varheightvalue` are server-side variables, just use this one:

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("GetData", "MyController", new { urlVar = Request.Url.ToString(), width = varwidthvalue, height = varheightvalue })';
```

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto how about if i use variable? My `myheight` and `mywidth`  is declared as static for now how if i need a value to it from variable also?

Comment: It depends how you want to assign values for them. For example, if you want to pass a server-side variable into client-side variable just use declaration like this: `var myWidth = @width` and then use `'mywidth': myWidth`.

Comment: how about if i need a value to it `myWidth` and `myheight` from javascript? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Simply pass them in JSON string as I said before: `data: "{'urlVar':'"+ currentUrl +"','mywidth': '" + myWidth + "','myheight': '" + myHeight + "'}",` (make sure you're already assigned both `myWidth` and `myHeight` variable).

Comment: yeah i got you, but my problem is i need to put width and height here `@Url.Action(` something like `new { urlVar = Request.Url.ToString(),width=varwidthvalue,height=varheightvalue }`

Comment: Updated the answer for multiple parameters, you need to use ampersand `&` as separator for client-side variables or comma for server-side variables to build URL query string.